# Approach for setting custom user culture in ASP.net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

In our asp.net MVC application, we allow users to select preferred language and save them in database.  Thus browser language settings are ignored.

If this setting needs to be read on every HTTP request, what is the best way to store it for a user session from performance/maintenance point of view?  I mean whether it would be a good practice to store it in regular asp.net session or cookie.  Is there any reason to avoid sessions?  What are good options in this situation?

Thank you.

Murtaza

Comment: Once the user selects preferred language is there any option to change it to other language or is it one time selection??

Comment: User can change his/her preferred language any time and save it in database.  On next login, his/her preferred language should be used to translate all pages.

Comment: Well, I would suggest, once he selects a language store it in a persistence cookie with a unique key of userName, as well as save it in database. Next everytime when the user logs in check the value of persistence cookie and if it is null fetch it from db. This cookie value gets changed only when the user changes the language. Minimal request to server or data fetching from server will give you increase in performance.

Comment: It seems when user changes language from different machines, it will be tricky to keep the cookie in sync.  For example, user sets language X from machine A.  Now he logs in from machine B and changes language to Y.  Then he comes back to machine A, how can the cookie be refreshed on machine A?  Use of session is being discouraged due to load balancing and web farm complications.

Comment: Then it's better if you get it on first request by user every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read relevant data from database and save it into HttpContext.Current in "Application_BeginRequest" in global.asax.

Comment: Thanks Gavin - are you suggesting to save this setting in regular ASP.net session?  Application_BeginRequest seems a good place to do it.  Only thing I was not sure about was whether choice of Session is a good one.

Comment: you can save this kind of data to asp.net session. but personally I don't suggest to do it.